# Powershell how to remove rows that aren't part of table data .csv file

Tags: sql, powershell

I am just starting out in Powershell and need a push in the right direction on a task I've been assigned. We get files from different 3rd party sources for the same process. These files come in varying formats so we are converting them all to .csv and then are going to import the data into SQL tables. The issue is that on some of the files there is 'data' that precedes the actual file data. This could be an address or some note, etc. but I am needing to delete these rows/records from the .csv file before loading the file data into a staging table. I was thinking about how to use 'usedrange' to find the max column value and then any row with a value less than this to get removed/deleted. Is this possible? Example of file:
[image]

In this files case i would need to remove the first 5 rows. In other files it could be remove 1, 10 or any number of rows including none. I have used a few powershell scripts to help me convert files and do some neat tricks but these were snippets that I copied and pasted to use when needed. My understanding of powershell is still in its infancy. Any help would be appreciated. I did look intensively for a solution online but couldn't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: Based on what you're showing, find the first **row** where the first **column** is populated.

Comment: Do these files - despite varying preambles - all use the same _separator_ (delimiter)? If so, which? Is it always the case that the preamble lines have an _empty first column_? Do the files have at least one shared column name? If so, is it always in the same position?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: the files with 'introductory' or rows with notes etc... that data can start in any column. but those rows always have less columns with data in them. they are all TAB delimited.

Comment: Is there always a _blank line_ before the actual data starts? Do the non-data lines have _fewer columns_ or the same number of columns, but with _empty values_? Do the data rows have a _minimum_ count of columns that predictably exceeds the column count of the non-data rows?

Comment: there can be blank rows or rows with an address field that has nothing to do with the table data in the file. Some files won't have this and the header row is row 1 and those are good. We are just trying to get rid of garbage or non-table data rows that come in the file more often than not. Some 3rd party companies will put there notes, etc. on a separate worksheet but some put them 'on top' or at the beginning of a worksheet where the real data lies. I'm thinking about trying to dump this into a SQL staging table and doing some logic to clean it that way. just thought powershell would offer..

Comment: I understand the intent, but unless you can come up with an - unambiguous - _algorithmic_ formulation of how to process the data - the elucidation of which my comments were aimed at - you won't be able to solve your problem _programmatically_.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by [**mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) without "*an - unambiguous - algorithmic formulation of how to process the data*" it is difficult to answer this question as shows from comment in the answer from [**Mitch**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138200/mitch) were you come up with an actual constrain "*files may have a different first Header column name*" which isn't defined in the question.
Anyways, let me try to formulate your intention, aka the definition where you would probably presume a table resides in a file:

> A table starts at any line that has more *valid* csv columns than any previous line.
> Any blank or invalid csv line will invalidate the current table and requires a new header (and table).

```
Get-Content .\Your.csv | Foreach-Object -begin {
    $Header = $Null
    $Table = @()
} -process {
    # Try to convert from csv with a header row equal to the data row
    $Names = Try { (ConvertFrom-Csv $_, $_).PSObject.Properties.Name } Catch {}
    if (!$Header -or @($Names).get_Count() -gt @($Header).Get_Count()) {
        $Header = $Names # (Re)start table
        $Table = [Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }
    else { # Add the data row
        $Data = Try { ConvertFrom-Csv $_ -Header $Header } Catch { $Header = $Null }
        if ($Data) { $Table.Add($Data) }
    }
} -end { $Table }
```

Comment: I did a small update as the previous version did accept to equal data values and therefore started a new table in that event.

Answer (score 0):

Copy one text file to another, skipping a constant number of lines using `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` with `Select-Object -Skip n`

```
Get-Content ex.csv | Select-Object -Skip 5 | Set-Content ex2.csv
```

If you don't know how many rows to skip, you may do so in a filter:

```
$found = $false;
Get-Content ex.csv | ?{
    If ($found) { $true }
    Else { ($found = $_.StartsWith('Item')) }
} | Set-Content ex2.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your skip using a filter but these files may have a different first Header column name in the file. So in my example here it is 'Item' but the next file it may be 'Catalog' or 'Account' or any number of different names.

Comment: It may be better to use `? {` / `% {` rather than `?{` / `%{`, because the former makes it clear that `?` / `%` and `{` are distinct syntax elements: a cmdlet name (`?` / `%` are aliases of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) / [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)), and `{`, the start of a [script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) passed as an _argument_ to the cmdlet.